# Find the modular residue of this product..

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Please help me solve this and please tell me how to do it..

$12345234 \times 23123345 \pmod {31} = $?

edit: please show me how to do it on a calculator not a computer thanks:)

Comment: My calculator doesn't show those big numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to replace these big numbers by much smaller ones that have the same remainder on division by $31$.

Take your first big number $12345234$. Divide by $31$ with the calculator. My display reads $398233.3548$. Subtract $398233$. My calculator shows $0.354838$. Multiply by $31$. The calculator gives $10.999978$. If it were perfect, it would say $11$.

Do the same with the other big number. My calculator again says $10.99978$, and if perfect would say $11$.

Multiply $11$ by $11$, and find the remainder when $121$ is divided by $31$. Again, we could use the calculator. But it can be done in one's head. The remainder when we divide by $31$ is $28$.

**Remark:** It can be fairly important not to write down an intermediate calculator result, and rekey. The reason is that the calculator inernally keeps *guard digits*, that is, it is calculating to greater precision than it displays. If you rekey, typing in only digits that you *see*, you will lose some of the built-in accuracy that you paid for. For similar reasons, it is useful to learn to make use of the *memory* features of your calculator.

Let's ee why the procedure we used works. When we divide $12345234$ by $31$, the stuff before the decimal point is the *quotient*. The remainder is unfortunately not given directly, but what's "left over" is (approximately) $0.354838$. This is a decimal representation of $\frac{r}{31}$, where $r$ is the (integer) remainder. To recover $r$, we multiply $0.354838$ by $31$. Because of internal roundoff, we usually don't get an integer, but most of the time, if the divisor (here $31$) is not too large, we get an answer that is very close to an integer, so we can quickly decide what $r$ must be.

Comment: Thanks great explanation:)

Comment: You are welcome. It really works quite well, and is a no unpleasant calculation. If the numbers were a couple of digits longer, the procedure would break down, since we couldn't even key the number in. We can adapt, but it definitely gets more complicated, and it is best to turn to more powerful tools.

Answer (score 1):

As $10^1\equiv 10\pmod{31},$

$10^2=100\equiv7,$

$10^3\equiv10\cdot7\equiv8,$

$10^4\equiv49\equiv18,$

$10^5=10^2\cdot10^3\equiv 7\cdot8\equiv25,$

$10^6=(10^3)^2\equiv8^2\equiv2,$

$10^7=10^4\cdot10^3\equiv18\cdot8\equiv20,$

$$12345234=4+3\cdot10+2\cdot10^2+5\cdot10^3+4\cdot10^4+3\cdot10^5+2\cdot10^6+1\cdot10^7$$
$$\equiv4+3\cdot10+2\cdot7+5\cdot8+4\cdot18+3\cdot25+2\cdot2+1\cdot20\pmod{31}$$